How to make the position of the arrow on a Material Tool tip dynamic (The arrow should point to the content it's coming from)?
I have this template from which I'm calling the mat tool tip
Template code:
<i class="characteristic-tooltip-icon"
                    #informationToolTip="matTooltip"
                    refxPopover
                    [ngClass]="'informative' | icon"
                    [matTooltip]="characteristic.additionalInformationKey | o3rTranslate:characteristic.additionalInformationArgs"
                    [attr.aria-label]="characteristic.additionalInformationKey | o3rTranslate:characteristic.additionalInformationArgs"
                    (click)="informationToolTip.toggle()">
</i>

The common style for this tooltip is here:
.mat-mdc-tooltip {
    background: $o3r-color-accent-A100 !important;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-top: 1.125rem;
    margin-inline-start: 1rem;

    .mdc-tooltip__surface {
      background-color: transparent !important;
      padding: .75rem;
      font-size: .75rem !important;
    }
  }

.mat-mdc-tooltip-panel-below {
  .mat-mdc-tooltip {
    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: 8px solid transparent;
      border-bottom-color: $o3r-color-accent-A100;
      display: block;
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
      bottom: 100% !important;
      left: 50%;

      [dir='rtl'] & {
        right: 50%;
      }
    }
  }
}

.mat-mdc-tooltip-panel-above {
  .mat-mdc-tooltip {
    &::before {
      content: '';
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100% !important;
      left: 50%;
      border: 8px solid transparent;
      border-top-color: $o3r-color-accent-A100;
      display: block;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);

      [dir='rtl'] & {
        right: 50%;
      }
    }
  }
}

As you can see the arrow points upward and downward accordingly.
But the position of the arrow always stays in the middle.
failing_case
As you can see when it is the edge of the screen, since the whole tooltip moves, the arrow doesn't look convincing.
Can you guys help me out here?
As far as I've understood, The left property should be adjusted dynamically. I couldn't find solutions out there on how to do it. ChatGPT is overkilling it, and it doesn't work.
Help me out :)
Stackblitz screenshot

Please add a stackblitz demo

You can use this as an example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wa7ea
In this example, the right value is similar to my left value, (in the styles.scss file)
And as you can see the output, If you increase the size of the tooltip content, (tooltip box) the arrow does not take right place

@T.Jami You can view the screenshot I have posted at the end to look the stackblitz.
